# Need help in creating an indicator in Pine Editor in TradingView

Tags: pine-script, trading

Hi I'm new to Pine editor . I'm trying to develop a strategy in Pine Editor. I want to know the value of candles in my defined set of time frames irrespective of user selected time frame.

What I mean here is lets say user is in 30 min time frame, now I want to apply an Indicator (Ichimoku) on weekly time frame and monthly time frame to get values of candles .

How can I achieve this . Kindly pardon me if I'm missing something very obvious.

```
study(title="Ichimoku Cloud", shorttitle="Ichimoku", overlay=true)
conversionPeriods = input(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Periods - Fast MA ")
basePeriods = input(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Periods - Slow MA")
laggingSpan2Periods = input(52, minval=1, title="Lagging Span 2 Periods")
displacement = input(26, minval=1, title="Displacement")
donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)
plot(conversionLine, color=#0496ff, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=#991515, title="Base Line")
plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#459915, title="Lagging Span")
p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=color.green,
     title="Lead 1")
p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=color.red,
     title="Lead 2")
fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.green : color.red)
```

Above code is code of Ichimoku indicator. I want to get conversionPeriods, basePeriods, laggingSpan2Periods,   p1 and p2 values in weekly and monthly time frames. How can I do this.

Comment: Your best bet will be to look up [MTF Ichi's in the Public Library](https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/search/MTF%20ichimoku/), see how they go about it. There are plenty of examples.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF I really appreciate ur help , I really do . But problem is I'm a beginner in pine script and I'm not able to understand those code since it is mostly code with no clear comments and explanation. So kindly help me in this. If you need any additional information Im ready to provide you .

Comment: This isn't an indicator-writing service. It's a forum where Pine coders help each other resolve coding challenges. A generous coder from here may volunteer to write your indicator, but don't hold your breath. 
 If you are interested in learning Pine, this is the best place to start: 
 https://www.pinecoders.com 
 If you need to hire someone to help you, we maintain a list of Trusted Pine Programmers for Hire here: 
 https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/rusted-pine-programmers-for-hire

Comment: I didn't asked anyone to write my complete indicator. By the way it is just a small portion of whole logic. I just needed some help in figuring things out as I'm a beginner. I just wanna know if there is method or some easy function to achieve what I'm trying. That's all I need just a push from the back.  Sorry if I have bothered you .